# "Different" looking question mark

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, libertine, newtxmath

I'm in a situation where I have a concept in my document that is traditionally represented using the question mark `?`.

However, for visual clarity, I would like to differentiate between the ordinary punctuation `?`, and my "special" use of it as a symbol.

I have tried `mathbb`, `mathcal`, and most of the other typical math font modes, but all of them seem to render `?` in an identical way (at least under the default options of the `acmart` class).

Is there some way that I can get a fancy `?` symbol? Bold, italic, black board, calligraphy, I'm open to different options. The inverted question mark is not an option, as it already carries meaning in my particular field.

EDIT:

For reference, if I do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathsf{?} ? \mathbf{?} \mathit{?} \mathbb{?} \mathcal{?}$
\end{document}
```

It renders as this: [image] i.e. there is no difference between the symbols.

The font used is Libertine, specifically the Libertine option of `newtxmath`, maybe this is part of the problem?

Comment: This is a bit vague.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, this is in math. I've updated to question to clarify that `mathbf` and `mathit` seem to do nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: exact same results on overleaf with a minimal complete document (question updated to include self-contained example)

Comment: @jmite yes well my initial comment was not as accurate as it could have been:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the text fonts or images

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

$?\,\textbf{?}\,\textit{?}\,\textsf{?}\,\includegraphics[height=.7em]{q}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @jmite do you want to buy that original mspaint artwork brushstroke? :-)

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of the character `?` in math is defined by

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{?}{\mathclose}{operators}{"3F}
```

so it isn't affected by math alphabet changing commands such as `\mathsf`. You can define

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\qm}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"3F}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % not really used here

\DeclareMathSymbol{\qm}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"3F}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\[
\qm\quad\mathrm{\qm}\quad
\mathit{\qm}\quad\mathsf{\qm}\quad
\mathtt{\qm}\quad\mathbbold{\qm}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach: find a font that has the glyph that suits your need and do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\qm}{\text{\usefont{OT1}{iwona}{m}{n}?}}

\begin{document}

\[
\qm
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Differently from using `\textbf` or `\textit`, both approaches will not be affected by the font current at the time math mode was entered. For instance, in a theorem statement, typically using italics, `$\textbf{?}$` would be typeset in boldface italic.